# Foreign data wrapper remote trigger cannot find a remote table

Tags: postgresql, triggers, sql-insert, postgresql-9.3, foreign-data-wrapper

**Remote schema:**

```
some_table
some_table_view
some_table_view_trigger (INSTEAD OF INSERT)
    -- tries to access some_table (select/update/insert)
```

**Local schema:**

```
some_table_view_fdw
    -- wraps some_table_view on remote
```

Now on local, when I run an `INSERT` on `some_table_view_fdw`, I get `relation not found: some_table`.

- I can select from some_table_view_fdw just fine (some_table_view just returns * from `some_table`).
- insert into some_table_view works just fine if run locally (on the remote). The trigger does what it should.
- Note that some_table_view_fdw does not reference some_table directly, so I guess the trigger must be running but then for some reason can't find it's own table?

I am using postgres 9.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that while querying a remote server `search_path` parameter is set to `pg_catalog`. References to tables in the schema `public` are therefore not automatically solved.

To resolve this problem use *absolute table names* in the trigger function, e.g. `public.my_table` instead of `my_table`. This also applies to all the functions and views used in triggers or views.

You can also set `search_path` in the trigger function, although I would not recommend this solution. When the trigger is fired locally, the quietly changed parameter will be in force until the end of the session, what could cause further confusions.

---

Treat it as a curiosity: how to check `search_path` on remote server with `postgres_fdw`?

Create the test table with the trigger on remote server (locally):

```
create table test_path (id int, val text);

create or replace function path_trigger()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
    select setting into new.val
    from pg_settings where name = 'search_path';
    return new;
end $$;

create trigger path_trigger
before insert on test_path
for each row execute procedure path_trigger();

insert into test_path (id) values (1) returning *;

 id |      val     
----+----------------
  1 | "$user",public
(1 row)
```

On local server create foreign table and fire the remote trigger:

```
create foreign table test_path (id int, val text)
server backup_server
options (schema_name 'public', table_name 'test_path'); 

insert into test_path (id) values (2) returning *;

 id |    val     
----+------------
  2 | pg_catalog
(1 row)
```

Comment: Had problems with a remote trigger function used on partitioning (creating tables inheriting the public.table). This solved my issue.